# useEffect on async operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm a little confused when to use `useEffect()` the majority of the examples I see only use `useEffect()` to pull data from an API and other examples of side effects, but I haven't seen people using `useEffect()` when sending POST request when the component will mount.

Then I was taking the course of Epic React, this custom hook confused me:

```
const useLocalStorageState = (key, value = "") => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(() => window.localStorage.getItem(key) || value)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, state)
  }, [key, state]);

  return [state, setState]
};
```

1. It confused me because they are not using `useEffect()` to read from the local storage, which is a side effect, they are using `useState()`, I would have used `useEffect()` then `useState()` to set the value of the `state` variable
2. `useEffect()` is being used for the side effect of writing to localStorage, if this was a POST request to an API, will `useEffect()` still apply?

Comment: for #1, what benefit would there be in your opinion to move `getItem` into `useEffect` ?

Comment: 1. Why would they use getItem? They want to update local storage on every state change 2. yes

Comment: @Evert For my little understanding of a lot of this( That's why I'm taking the Epic react course) if I'm pulling data that I need before the component will mount, I use the `useEffect` which can help you avoid side effects with that re-renders?

Comment: @devpato that sounds reasonable, i think I can answer this =)

Comment: @DennisVash it's a tic tac toe game and yes, they want to save the `state` of the game so every time I make a move, gets stored in localstorage and if I refresh the page, I see the `state` of the game who it was before I refreshed the page.

 I think the author is using `useState` to get the state every time the state changes but isn't this doable via useEffect as well if I don't pass the dependency array? This looks like a shortcut by just using `useState()`. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It confused me because they are not using useEffect() to read from the local storage, which is a side effect, they are using useState(), I would have used useEffect() then useState() to set the value of the state variable

A good reason to use `useEffect` is that it can prevent the call to `localStorage.getItem()`, for every render.

However, this would be needed if you *did* call `localStorage.getItem()`, for every render.

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(
  () => window.localStorage.getItem(key) || value
)
```

In this example, `getItem` is not called for each render. It's only used in the callback passed to `getState()`. This is the initial value and it will only be used on the very first render. So, it solves the same problem.

> useEffect() is being used for the side effect of writing to localStorage, if this was a POST request to an API, will useEffect() still apply?

It *may* be useful in `useEffect`, but it depends on the situation. In many cases a `POST` request could be triggered when the user presses a button (`submit` or `click` events). In those cases the POST request is likely triggered from event handlers.

If you need to always do a POST on specific React lifecycle events (update, mount, etc), they would need to be in `useEffect`.

Comment: Evert, thanks for answering. Now, if I use getItem() inside of a useEffect and add that to the dependency array, wouldn't this be called only one time and doing the same as the code I provided?

Comment: It depends what you put in `useState` as the default value. `useEffect()` will only ever change the second render.